# Setting path for Python in PowerShell?

Tags: python, powershell, path

I have two Python versions on my machine (Windows Vista), 2.6 (located in C/Program files) and 2.7 (located in C/).

1- I open PowerShell
2- I type python, and it calls python 2.6.1.
3- I want to change the path for Python 2.7, so I type: 
*[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("Path", "$env:Path;C:\Python27", "User")*
4- and then when I run python again it still calls the version 2.6. and there is no way I can change it. I also tried to restart the computer after changing the path, with no success.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to set the path in the Environment Variables settings so it would be kept after closing shell and/or reboot.

Computer (right-click) > Properties > Advanced System Settings > Environment Variables

You can create a new user variable called `Path`, or append to the system one (so it'd affect all users).

Add your Python27 directory there in the `Path` system variable (with a `;` as a separator). You can swap them (`C:\Python26;C:\Python27` and `C:\Python27;C:\Python26`) to change the default one.

[image]

Comment: @amr125 By the way, I saw that you're new to StackOverflow. You can accept the answer that worked for you by clicking on the checkmark near the answer's rating.

Answer (score 3):

Python 2.6.1 is already in your path as demonstrated by item number 2 in your list.  On number 3, you're adding Python 2.7 to your path *after* Python 2.6.1's entry.  You need to remove Python 2.6.1 from your environment variable, or at a minimum, set it so that 2.7 is listed first.