# SciPy in CMD works, but not IDLE

Tags: python, windows, numpy, scipy

I am running Windows 7 Professional

I have installed Python 3.6

My version was verified by pip --version to give the following:

```
pip 9.0.1 from C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages (python 3.6)
```

Using PIP I have installed NumPy and SciPy by the following:

```
pip install numpy
pip install scipy
```

I can verify the instalation using pip list to show:

```
cffi (1.9.1)
conda (4.2.13)
cryptography (1
idna (2.2)
menuinst (1.4.4
numpy (1.12.1+m
pip (9.0.1)
pyasn1 (0.1.9)
pycosat (0.6.1)
pycparser (2.17
pyOpenSSL (16.2
pywin32 (220)
requests (2.12.
scipy (0.19.0)
setuptools (27.
six (1.10.0)
wheel (0.29.0)
```

In the command prompt I can type python, and then import scipy like so:

```
C:\Users\james.hayek\Desktop>python
Python 3.6.0 |Continuum Analytics, Inc.| (default, Dec 23 2016, 11:57:41) [MSC v
.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import scipy
>>>
```

It would appear as if everything has installed correctly. However, when I start IDLE and type import scipy I get the following error:

```
>>> import scipy
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#8>", line 1, in <module>
    import scipy
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'scipy'
>>>
```

Any idea's how I can call/import SciPy in IDLE?

Comment: Do you have more than one version of python installed?  Check the version of python that IDLE is running.

Comment: @Trevor I only have one version of Python installed. IDLE shows Python 3.6.1 Shell

Comment: @Trevor I only installed one version of Python... But it seems like CMD shows Python 3.6.0 and IDLE says Python 3.6.1 Shell in its title. I'm not sure how to correct this.

Answer (score 1):

Your Miniconda package has made its own Python SDK default. You need to run your IDLE and add Miniconda's site-packages directory to your regular PYTHONPATH:

`import sys
print(sys.path) # to verify that Miniconda is not in this PYTHONPATH
sys.path.append('C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages')`

To check your path you can equally go to File -> Path Browser

Comment: Well, you are exactly correct. Thanks!! So, now that I added Miniconda to the PYTHONPATH in IDLE I can run the module. However, when I close IDLE and reopen, I have to append the path again. Is there a way to set this once?

Comment: To achieve this, please follow the instructions to modify your environment variables as described in [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28416182/setting-path-for-python-in-powershell) question. Add your Miniconda's site-packages to the PATH. I would highly recommend to start working with the instruments like `virtualenv` to avoid confusion and ensure library compatibilities.

Comment: I actually did that. It still is not being recognized. Here is my PATH contents: C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages; C:\Users\james.hayek\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Scripts\; C:\Users\james.hayek\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\; C:\Python27\Scripts;

Comment: You should work with the `Path` system variable, not `PATH` then. Add your Miniconda directory there.

Comment: In the system properties advanced tab, I chose enviornment variables, then under the System Variables section I was a variable called "Path" I have added the directory path there to no avail. Still doesnt work.. not sure why

Comment: The path content for MiniConda is here: ;C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3;C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\Scripts; C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\Library\bin; C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages;

Comment: Let's do the workaround here: 
1.Identify the default directory that you've got from python.org
do `import sys; print(sys.executable)` in IDLE.
2. Set up new system variable called PYTHONHOME with the values `path_to_orig_interpreter, e.g. C:\Python27`; use 1 to ensure.
3. Modify your `Path` to include `%PYTHONHOME%; %PYTHONHOME%\DLLs; C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages`
You can alternatively install numpy and scipy directly from IDLE. Read more [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40364945/run-pip-in-idle). Installs them into the site-packages of your IDLE's 'environment'.

Comment: Looks like I can't follow directions, I had trouble doing the above. HOWEVER, I was able to uninstall Python and by using the approach given to install from IDLE, I decided to take a similar approach using conda. Once Python was uninstalled I reinstalled it using Conda, which then upgraded Python 3.6.0 to 3.6.1 and now all the libraries work. Thank you @dr_dronych